# Why doesn't this haskell type signature work?

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature

New guy at haskell here. I'm trying to get better at writing type signatures and this simple one doesn't want to work. I'm wondering why:

```
average :: Num a => [a] -> a
average ns = sum ns `div` length ns
```

Average should take any number and return some number. However I get the error

```
test.hs 11:27:
    Couldn't match expected type 'a' with actual type 'Int'
       'a' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for average :: Num a => [a] -> a
        at test.hs:10:12
    Relevant bindings include
        ns:: [a] (bound at test.hs:11:9)
        average :: [a] -> a (bound at test.hs:11:1)
    In the second argument of 'div' namely 'length ns'
    In the expression: sum ns `div ` length ns
```

It seems to be saying length isn't getting what it's expecting. Can anyone help?

Comment: it's because `length ns` is an `Int` but `div` works for `Integral a => a -> a -> a` - try `average ns = sum ns `div` (fromIntegral $ length ns)` - it should work

Comment: but on small thing: `div` needs `Integral` anyway !

Comment: `length :: [q] -> Int` so `average :: [Int] -> Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok this will work:

```
average :: Integral a => [a] -> a
average ns = sum ns `div` (fromIntegral $ length ns)
```

please note that `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` so you need `Integral a`  instead of just `Num a` (which has no division)

And because `length` will return an `Int` so you need the `fromIntegral` to work around it.

Comment: hmm I didn't even think about using :type to figure out what div is. Thanks for your help

Comment: np - the numbers and their relation/conversion always get me too - the real fun starts with floating, sin, etc. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The type of `div` is `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, which means that both of its arguments have to be of the same type.  In this case, the second argument is always of type `Int` (the result of `length`), but the first argument is of type `a`.

In addition, you're trying to write a function that works for any kind of `Num`, but `div` only works for integegral types.  If you want to support "averaging" lists of integral values (with the result also being rounded to an integer), you could do:

```
average :: Integral a => [a] -> a
average ns = sum ns `div` fromIntegral (length ns)
```

The `fromIntegral` will convert the `Int` length into whatever integral type `a` is (which might be `Int`, or something like `Integer`).

To avoid rounding error, you'll need to use fractional division on fractional types:

```
average :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
average ns = sum ns / fromIntegral (length ns)
```

Comment: good point - I indeed forgot that maybe `div` is not the best idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have well highlighted the issue with `Num` vs. `Integral` an offer to use a cast after calling `length`. Alternatively, you could use `genericLength` from `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List

average :: Integral a => [a] -> a
average ns = sum ns `div` genericLength ns
```